# ASP.Net Checkboxlist Background color

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkboxlist on aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCalendarFilter" runat="server" />
```

I add the listItems from code behind.

```
newCkItm = new ListItem();
newCkItm.Text = childrenFoldersData[i].Description.Trim();
newCkItm.Value = childrenFoldersData[i].Id.ToString().Trim();
newCkItm.Selected = true;
```

I can add the background of the ListItem by

```
newCkItm.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Red;");
```

The colors will be different from one item to another and the name of the item will also be different. So, the problem is the background color is only covering the text length. The background color is not aligned for all Items. I checked with the inspector and found out that..

- The background color style is applying to `<span>` surrounding the text
- All spans are inside the `<td>`.

I am wondering if there is a way to apply that style to `<td>` without much effort. I'd rather not use jquery and javascript by searching the name.

Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a style attribute to each item, and because you mentioned each item needs a different background colour, I'd add an id attribute:

```
newCkItm.Attributes.Add("id", "alpha");
```

That way you can keep all your styles separate from your code and not have to recompile, etc. every time you need to tweak the CSS.

With the `<asp:CheckBoxList />` the CSS itself would look something like this:

```
#cblCalendarFilter {
    border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#cblCalendarFilter td {
    padding:0;
}

#cblCalendarFilter span {
    display:block;
    padding:2px;
}

#cblCalendarFilter #alpha {
    background:red;
}

#cblCalendarFilter #beta {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Hopefully making the span block-level will fix the issue you had with the background colour only covering the text length.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and found this solution & it worked for me.

Just try to give padding-right 
for example:

```
newCkItm.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Red;padding-right:30px");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use a Repeater which has tr/td with `CheckBox` inside it and do the logic on the `ItemDataBound` event where you can retrieve the td:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td id="myTd" runat="server">
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myCheckBox" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that.. I am thinkin how to do that by using Asp.Net checkbox list

Comment: Your request is not that common, so you need a special way to treat it :)

Comment: What if you would change the Font color instead, that wouldn't be so "eye disturbing'?

Comment: I would if I could.. But the design specification is to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way, you have to individually access the element and assign the css to items. I tend to use foreach loop, access the item and add attributes. TBH, I would stay with checkboxlist compared to repeater, unless I need some extra functionality